# mysql/php/javascript/css Calendar adivce

Tags: php, mysql, css, calendar

I need to implement a calendar on a website that is data driven (php/mysql).  I need more than a js or css datepicker.  The calendar needs to be able to integrate with events and people in a mysql database.  From what I've read, there aren't any good scripts or tutorials for mysql driven calendars.  However, I thought someone might have some ideas.

There does seem to be a good jquery calendar called Full Calendar but it doesn't seem to offer much in the way of support for mysql calls or data storage.  And I've also seen google calendar recommended but I have a feeling this would make integration with events and people on my website very difficult.

There seem to be lots of beautiful calendars out there that must be data driven as in this link:

```
http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/03/25/19-css-html-calendars-for-your-next-web-application/
```

But I have been unable to find any suggestions on how to connect these nice front ends to a back end.

Another article said building your own calendar is really a time sink.  However, there don't seem to be any good alternatives out there.

Would appreciate any suggestions for how to approach this problem.

Comment: there is no need for a client side script to access database or mysql, what you need to do is to create a script (on server side) to pull data from database and serve it to the client side script, in other word, you should generate a JSON data based on your database and provide it to a jQuery plugin like full calendar that support JSON data

Answer (score 0):

I had made a function similar to what you are asking for. It basically generates a calendar using a table, and you can pass an optional array that is structured by dates (i.e 2013-06-22)
so it would expect an array similar to this:
`$array['2013-06-22']['data']`

You can then customize the function and display the data as you need. or You can simply execute your query in the function (there should be a comment in the function to hint you where you can run your query).. i also remembered that there are alot of comments in there.. which i'm too lazy to remove, so you might wanna clean it up a little.

To be honest this function is an old version and i had an improved version but can't seem to find it atm.

Hope you find it useful :)

```
/**
* Display Calendar (and Optional Data structured by date)
* @author: Zubair Baig
*/
function show_calendar_old($month = '', $year = '', $dataByDate = '')
{
    $listOfDaysInWeek = array('01'=>'Sunday', '02'=>'Monday',
                                  '03'=>'Tuesday', '04'=>'Wednesday',
                                  '05'=>'Thursday', '06'=>'Friday',
                                  '07'=>'Saturday');

    $month = !empty($month) ? $month : date('m', time());
    $year = !empty($year) ? $year : date('y', time());
    $dataByDate = is_array($dataByDate) ? $dataByDate : array();

    $calendar = '<table class="calendar">'.PHP_EOL;
    //$days_in_month = days_in_month($month, $year);

    $days_headings = $listOfDaysInWeek;

    //Table Head
    $calendar.= '<thead>'.PHP_EOL;
    $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">'.PHP_EOL;
    $calendar.= '<th class="calendar-day-head">';
    $calendar.= implode('</th>'.PHP_EOL.'<th class="calendar-day-head">', $days_headings);
    $calendar.= '</th>'.PHP_EOL;
    $calendar.= '</tr>'.PHP_EOL;
    $calendar.= '</thead>'.PHP_EOL;

    //Table Foot
    $calendar.= '<tfoot>'.PHP_EOL;
    $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">'.PHP_EOL;
    $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-head">';
    $calendar.= implode('</td>'.PHP_EOL.'<td class="calendar-day-head">', $days_headings);
    $calendar.= '</td>'.PHP_EOL;
    $calendar.= '</tr>'.PHP_EOL;
    $calendar.= '</tfoot>'.PHP_EOL;

    $days_counter = 0;
    //$running_day = date('w', strtotime('now'));
    $running_day = date('w', mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_month = date('t', mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
    $days_in_week = 7;
    $days_in_this_week = 1;
    //var_dump( $days_in_month, $running_day );

    $dates_array = array();

    //Table Body
    $calendar.= '<tbody>'.PHP_EOL;
    /* row for week one */
    $calendar.= '<tr>'.PHP_EOL;

    /* print "blank" days until the first of the current week */
    for($x = 0; $x < $running_day; $x++)
    {
        $calendar.= '<td>&nbsp;</td>'.PHP_EOL;
        $days_in_this_week++;
    }

    /* keep going with days.... */
    for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++)
    {
        $classes = '';//reset
        if (isset($dataByDate) && is_array($dataByDate))
        {
            $runningCalDateTimeStamp = mktime(0,0,0,$month,$list_day,$year);
            $runningCalDate = date('Y-m-d', $runningCalDateTimeStamp);

            if (in_array($runningCalDate, $dataByDate))
            {
                if (date('Y-m-d', time()) > $runningCalDate)
                {
                    $classes = ' day-can-be-reserved-but-old';
                } else {
                    $classes = ' day-can-be-reserved';
                }
            } else {
                $classes = ' day-cannot-be-reserved';
            }

            if (date('Y-m-d', time()) == $runningCalDate)
            {
                $classes .= ' day-is-today';
            }
        }

        $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day' .$classes. '">'.PHP_EOL;
            /* add in the day number */
            $calendar.= '<div class="day-number">'.$list_day.'</div>'.PHP_EOL;

            /** QUERY THE DATABASE FOR AN ENTRY FOR THIS DAY !!  IF MATCHES FOUND, PRINT THEM !! **/
            $calendar.= str_repeat('<input type="checkbox" name="selectedDates" value="' .day_with_zero($list_day). '" />'.PHP_EOL,1);

            //var_dump(in_array( date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0,$month,$list_day,$year)), $plDates));
            //var_dump(date('Y-m-d',mktime(0,0,0,$month,$list_day,$year)));

            if (isset($dataByDate) && is_array($dataByDate))
            {
                if (in_array(date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0,$month,$list_day,$year)), $dataByDate))
                {
                    //$calendar.= $list_day;
                }
            }
        $calendar.= '</td>'.PHP_EOL;

            if($running_day == 6)
            {
                $calendar.= '</tr>'.PHP_EOL;
                if(($days_counter + 1) != $days_in_month)
                {
                    $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">'.PHP_EOL;
                }
                $running_day = -1;
                $days_in_this_week = 0;
            }

            $days_in_this_week++;
            $running_day++;
            $days_counter++;
    }

    /* finish the rest of the days in the week */
    if($days_in_this_week < 8 && $running_day != 0)
    {
        for($x = 1; $x <= (8 - $days_in_this_week); $x++)
        {
            $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np">&nbsp;</td>'.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

    //final row
    $calendar.= '</tr>'.PHP_EOL;
    $calendar.= '</tbody>'.PHP_EOL;
    $calendar.= '</table>'.PHP_EOL;
    echo $calendar;
}
```